# How can I create a macro

Tags: python

I need to create a macro that when I press the [E] key it does execute the following commands with a little delay

[CTRL]

Delay 15

[Right Mouse Button]

Delay 150

[CTRL]

Delay 50

[Right mouse button]

stay pressed for 5 seconds

---

Toggles the [Y] key on and off

Closes on the [X] key

Comment: The [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module might be able to help. If you need to do mouse stuff too, the [mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/) module might also be useful

Comment: Any particular reason you feel the need to use python for this, instead of using a tool like [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) that would affect the entire computer?

Comment: ahk is very bad.

Comment: ```pyautogui``` might help too

Comment: Are those delays, such as 150, in seconds? milliseconds? nanoseconds?

Comment: Do you want the program to do the following: "1) press `ctrl` key 2) wait 15 seconds 3) press Right Mouse Button" or do you want "1) pressing `ctrl` key sets the time delay variable to 15 seconds. 2) pressing right mouse button sets delay variable to 150 seconds. `E` runs program with the given delay variable"

Comment: delays: milliseconds